# Spring boot @SpyBean tries to instantiate a new bean instead of spying the one in context

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to unit-testing a Spring batch job inside Spring boot using JUnit.
I wrote this test class where I want to spy the bean ItemReader :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles({"dev", "batch", "test-jobs"})
public class BatchJobTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    private @Autowired @Qualifier("contactDownloadAckJob") Job contactDownloadAckTaskJob;

    @SpyBean
    private ItemReader<CrsOscContact> reader;

    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        given(this.reader.read()).willReturn(new CrsOscContact());
        //... blah blah blah
    }   

}
```

When I run this test, it seems that the @SpyBean annotation does not do its job, that should be proxying the ItemReader bean that's already present in the context, and so I obtain the (correct) exception because, as per definition, if the bean is not found it tries to instantiate a new bean of that type (and I have specified an interface) :

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: Specified class is an interface
```

I'm pretty sure that the bean (of ItemReader type) is already in the context because :

- debugging, I see that the target bean instantiation is correctly processed
- if I change the @SpyBean annotation to an @Autowired annotation, the instance of previous point is correctly injected

Any hint? Thank you

Comment: In the meanwhile I opened a Github issue, because spying other beans works like a charm : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7625

Comment: did you try this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698827/spring-aop-aspectj-afterreturning-advice-wrongly-executed-while-mockingbefo/62809074#62809074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a Spring Core issue, now fixed.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7625

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15011