# Spring AOP + AspectJ: @AfterReturning advice wrongly executed while mocking(before actual execution)

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop, spring-test, spring-boot-test

In an integration test, my advice of `@AfterReturning` is wrongly executed while in the test I mock it to throw TimeoutException, and the arg passed to the aspect is null.

My advice:

```java
    @AfterReturning("execution(* xxxxxx" +
            "OrderKafkaProducerService.sendOrderPaidMessage(..)) && " +
            "args(order)")
    public void orderComplete(CheckoutOrder order) { // order is null when debugging
        metricService.orderPaidKafkaSent();
        log.trace("Counter inc: order paid kafka"); // this line of log is shown in console
        metricService.orderCompleted();
        log.trace("Order complete! {}", order.getId()); // this line is not, because NPE
    }
```

And my test:

```java
// mocking
doThrow(new ServiceException(new TimeoutException("A timeout occurred"), FAILED_PRODUCING_ORDER_MESSAGE))
    .when(orderKafkaProducerService).sendOrderPaidMessage(any()); // this is where advice is executed, which is wrong

...
// when
(API call with RestAssured, launch a real HTTP call to endpoint; service is called during this process)

// then
verify(orderKafkaProducerService).sendOrderPaidMessage(any(CheckoutOrder.class)); // it should be called
verify(metricService, never()).orderCompleted(); // but we are throwing, not returning, we should not see this advice executed
```

This test is failing because of NPE(order is null).

In debugging, I find that **when I was mocking, I already execute the advice, and at this point, `any()` has no value yet, is null, so NPE**. But I don't think the advice should execute while mocking. How can I avoid that while testing?? This is absurd for me.

Comment: First of all, I don't know if you use Spring AOP or full AspectJ. This makes a difference because their AOP implementations are not the same (the former uses proxies, the latter does not, among other differences). Also, I cannot copy and run your code snippets because they are just fragmentary and I cannot debug fragments. As for mock frameworks, I guess you use Mockito, but you did not tell. Most mock frameworks create mocks again using dynamic proxies, i.e. subclasses.

Comment: Probably Spring AOP is wired to the Spring proxy, not to the mock object you create. But this is only a guess and impossible for me to say for sure without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally a small but runnable project on GitHub, reproducing your problem. I am not a Mockito user, but know AOP and how proxies work, so I could take a look. The question is interesting enough.

Comment: OK I will provide one example project these days, thanks!

Comment: If you are not in a hurry because this is just a little playground project and not something your boss expects you to produce quick results with, take as much time as you like. I am in no hurry at all.

Comment: OK now you have it, I reproduced it here: https://github.com/WesternGun/spring-boot-reactive-webflux-template (at least for "extra invocation while mocking" part), but I think that's enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Spring test support does not explicitly handle the situation that an injected mock or spy (which is a proxy subclass via Mockito) might actually be an AOP target later on (i.e. proxied and thus subclassed again via CGLIB).

There are several bug tickets related to this topic for Spring, Spring Boot and Mockito. Nobody has done anything about it yet. I do understand why the Mockito maintainers won't include Spring-specific stuff into their code base, but I do not understand why the Spring people do not improve their testing tools.

Actually when debugging your [failing test](https://github.com/WesternGun/spring-boot-reactive-webflux-template/blob/master/src/itest/java/com/example/template/OrderControllerITest.java) and inspecting `kafkaService`, you will find out the following facts:

1. `kafkaService.getClass()` is `com.example.template.services.KafkaService$MockitoMock$92961867$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8fc4fe95`
2. `kafkaService.getClass().getSuperclass()` is `com.example.template.services.KafkaService$MockitoMock$92961867`
3. `kafkaService.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass()` is `class com.example.template.services.KafkaService`

In other words:

1. `kafkaService` is a CGLIB Spring AOP proxy.
2. The AOP proxy wraps a Mockito spy (probably a ByteBuddy proxy).
3. The Mockito spy wraps the original object.

Besides, changing the wrapping order to make the Mockito spy the outermost object would not work because CGLIB deliberately makes its overriding methods final, i.e. you cannot extend and override them again. If Mockito was just as restrictive, the hierarchical wrapping would not work at all.

Anyway, what can you do?

- Either you use a sophisticated approach like described in [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-mock-spring-bean-version-2)
- or you go for the cheap solution to explicitly unwrap an AOP proxy via `AopTestUtils.getTargetObject(Object)`. You can call this method safely because if the passed candidate object is not a Spring proxy (internally easy to identify because it implements the `Advised` interface which also gives access to the target object), it just returns the passed object again.

In your case the latter solution would look like this:

```java
@Test
void shouldCompleteHappyPath() {
    // fetch spy bean by unwrapping the AOP proxy, if any
    KafkaService kafkaServiceSpy = AopTestUtils.getTargetObject(kafkaService);
    // given mocked
    doNothing().when(kafkaServiceSpy).send(ArgumentMatchers.any());
    // when (real request)
    testClient.create().expectStatus().isOk();
    // then
    verify(kafkaServiceSpy).send(ArgumentMatchers.any());
    verify(metricService).incKafka();
}
```

This has the effect that `when(kafkaServiceSpy).send(ArgumentMatchers.any())` no longer triggers the aspect advice because `kafkaServiceSpy` is no longer an AOP proxy. The auto-wired bean `kafkaService` still is, though, thus AOP gets triggered as expected, but no longer unwantedly while recording the mock interaction.

Actually, for the verification you could even use `kafkaService` instead of the spy and only unwrap the spy when recording the interaction you want to verify later:

```java
@Test
void shouldCompleteHappyPath() {
    // given mocked
    doNothing()
      .when(
        // fetch spy bean by unwrapping the AOP proxy, if any
        AopTestUtils.<KafkaService>getTargetObject(kafkaService)
      )
      .send(ArgumentMatchers.any());
    // when(real request)
    testClient.create().expectStatus().isOk();
    // then
    verify(kafkaService).send(ArgumentMatchers.any());
    verify(metricService).incKafka();
}
```

---

P.S.: Without your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I would never have been able to debug this and find out what the heck was going on. This proves again that asking questions including an MCVE is the best thing you can do for yourself because it helps you get answers to questions which otherwise probably would remain unanswered.

---

**Update:** After I had mentioned this problem under the similar closed issue [Spring Boot #6871](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6871#issuecomment-655940733), one of the maintainers has by himself created [Spring Boot #22281](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22281) which specifically addresses your problem here. You might want to watch the new issue in order to find out if/when it can be fixed.

Comment: **Update:** added links to related Spring Boot issues.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Much appreciated.